# Assembly Binding Redirection: v4 app using v2 libraries, need to be using v2 redirects

Tags: .net-4.0, inno-setup, machine.config

What is the best way to configure my .Net 4 application to use the third party library redirects located in the .Net 2 machine.config other than copying the entries?

If copying the entries is the only way, how can I do that using InnoSetup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a .Net executable to handle copying the entries and launched it from my InnoSetup script.